# Gremlin query has strange behavior with range() and limit()

Tags: graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have a Neptune database and use gremlin to query it. I have user vertices that could be connected with edges like "friends", "follows", "blocks", "reports". I want to make a query that gives "suggestions" to the user by presenting him with users that the people he follows follow. These users shouldn't be followed, blocked, or reported by the the current user and also should be up to 3 suggestions per user he follows.

I have constructed the following query :

```
g
  .V(userId)
  .Out("follows")
  .As(ConnectingFollowerLabel)
  .Local<Vertex>(__
     .Out("follows")
     .HasLabel("User")
     .Not(__.Both("blocks").HasId(userId))
     .Not(__.In("reported").HasId(userId))
     .Not(__.In("follows").HasId(userId))
     .Not(__.HasId(userId))
     .Limit<Vertex>(maxProfileSuggestionsPerCommonUser))
 .Dedup();
```

As it is it returns the results as it should. But for users that follow many users it gets kind of slow, so I added a limit() on the users fetched and added pagination with range() like this

```
g
  .V(userId)
  .Out("follows")
  .As(ConnectingFollowerLabel)
  .Local<Vertex>(__
     .Out("follows")
     .HasLabel("User")
     .Not(__.Both("blocks").HasId(userId))
     .Not(__.In("reported").HasId(userId))
     .Not(__.In("follows").HasId(userId))
     .Not(__.HasId(userId))
     .Limit<Vertex>(maxProfileSuggestionsPerCommonUser))
 .Limit<Vertex>(maxProfileSuggestions)
 .Dedup()
 .Range<Vertex>(Scope.Global, offset, offsetLimit);
```

As soon as I add the limit and range step the results change and I get suggestions with people I already follow. I tried ordering the result before the range step but that doesn't seem to work either.

A sample graph to be used with the query could be this:

```
g.addV('User').property(id, '1').as('1')
    .addV('User').property(id, '2').as('2')
    .addV('User').property(id, '3').as('3')
    .addV('User').property(id, '4').as('4')
    .addV('User').property(id, '5').as('5')
    .addV('User').property(id, '6').as('6')
    .addV('User').property(id, '7').as('7')
    .addV('User').property(id, '8').as('8')
    .addV('User').property(id, '9').as('9')
    .addV('User').property(id, '10').as('10')
    .addE('follows').from('1').to('2')
    .addE('follows').from('1').to('3')
    .addE('follows').from('1').to('4')
    .addE('follows').from('1').to('5')
    .addE('follows').from('1').to('6')
    .addE('follows').from('1').to('7')
    .addE('friend_requests').from('1').to('8')
    .addE('report_citizen').from('1').to('8')
    .addE('blocks').from('1').to('7')
    .addE('follows').from('2').to('3')
    .addE('follows').from('2').to('4')
    .addE('follows').from('2').to('5')
    .addE('follows').from('2').to('6')
    .addE('follows').from('2').to('7')
    .addE('follows').from('2').to('8')
    .addE('follows').from('3').to('7')
    .addE('follows').from('3').to('8')
    .addE('follows').from('3').to('9')
    .addE('follows').from('3').to('10')
    .addE('follows').from('4').to('5')
    .addE('follows').from('4').to('6')
    .addE('follows').from('4').to('7')
    .addE('follows').from('4').to('8')
    .addE('follows').from('5').to('3')
    .addE('follows').from('5').to('6')
    .addE('follows').from('5').to('7')
    .addE('follows').from('5').to('8')
    .addE('follows').from('5').to('9')
    .addE('follows').from('5').to('10')
    .addE('follows').from('8').to('1')
```

Comment: Are you able to update the question to include the `addV` and `addE` steps that build a sample graph that can be used to reproduce the problem? If so, that will really help investigate the issues you are seeing.

Comment: Certainly. I updated it with a sample that can be used with my use case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for doing that - I will try to take a look, unless someone else beats me to it :-)

Comment: Do you have the exact query to reproduce it ? I tried running the query provided and I am getting expected results.

Comment: @MavroudisMantonitsas - I was able to reproduce an odd behavior here when I used a `range(0, 1)` but not with any other range values.  Is this what you saw?